# Transfer data from old Access database to new

Tags: java, sql, database

What I have is an old Access database that needs to be cleaned up. I am first trying to to take the fields from the old database and insert them into the new database.  I am able to connect to both the databases but no records are being inserted into the new DB Employee table. Not sure if there is something wrong with my SQL. Can anyone please help?

Run.java:

```
package javaapplication1; 

/** 
 * 
 * @author Tyler Bradshaw 
 */

public class Run { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Convert.ConnectToOld(); 
        Convert.ConnectToNew(); 
        Convert.EmployeeTransfer(); 

    } 
}
```

Convert.java:

```
package javaapplication1; 

/** 
 * 
 * @author Tyler Bradshaw 
 */
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class Convert { 

    static DbWork oldDatabase = new DbWork(); 
    static DbWork newDatabase = new DbWork(); 

    public static void ConnectToOld(){ 
        oldDatabase.Constructor("oldDatabase"); 
        if (oldDatabase.isConnected()) 
            System.out.println("Connected to old database."); 
    } 

    public static void ConnectToNew(){ 
        newDatabase.Constructor("newDatabase"); 
        if (newDatabase.isConnected()) 
            System.out.println("Connected to new database."); 
    } 

    public static void EmployeeTransfer(){ 

        String readOld = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable"; 

        try{ 
            if (!oldDatabase.isConnected()){ 
                ConnectToOld(); 
            } 
            if (!newDatabase.isConnected()){ 
                ConnectToNew(); 
            } 
            oldDatabase.processQuery(readOld); 
            while(oldDatabase.nextRecord()){ 
               String empID = oldDatabase.getField("ID"); 
               String fName = oldDatabase.getField("First Name"); 
               String lName = oldDatabase.getField("Last Name"); 
               String mI = oldDatabase.getField("MI"); 
               String homeAdd = oldDatabase.getField("Home Address"); 
               String state = oldDatabase.getField("State"); 
               String zip = oldDatabase.getField("Zip"); 
               String dob = oldDatabase.getField("Date of Birth"); 
               String hireDate = oldDatabase.getField("Hire Date"); 
               String termDate = oldDatabase.getField("Termination Date"); 
               String licDate = oldDatabase.getField("License Date"); 

               /* validation */

               String loadNew = "INSERT INTO EmployeeTable (EmployeeID, FirstName,"
                + "LastName, MI, HomeAddress, Sta , ZIP, DateOfBirth, HireDate,"
                + "TerminationDate, LicenseDate) VALUES ('empID', '" + fName + "', '" + lName + "', '" + mI + "',"
                + "'" + homeAdd + "', '" + state + "', '" + zip + "', '" + dob + "', '" + hireDate + "', '" + termDate + "', '" + licDate + "')"; 
               newDatabase.processUpdate(loadNew); 
            } 
            System.out.println("Done?"); 
            } 

        catch (Exception ex) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error"); 


        } 
    } 

}
```

DbWork.java:

```
package javaapplication1; 


import java.sql.*; 

public class DbWork { 

    private Connection connection; 
    private ResultSet rs; 
    private String errorMessage; 

    public void Constructor(String dsn) { 
        try { 
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
            String URL = "jdbc:odbc:"+dsn; 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"",""); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            errorMessage = "Cannot Connect to Database."; 
        }   
    } 

    public boolean isConnected() { 
        try { 
            if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) { 
                return false; 
            } else { 
                return true; 
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    public boolean processQuery(String selectQuery) {         
        try { 
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectQuery); 
            return true; 
        } 

        catch (Exception l) { 
            errorMessage = "Result Set for query failed."; 
            rs = null; 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    public boolean nextRecord() {  
        try { 
            if (rs.next()) { 
                return true; 
            } else { 
                errorMessage = "End of File"; 
                return false; 
            } 
        }  
        catch (Exception e) { 
            errorMessage = "Exception occured when moving to next record."; 
            return false;     
        } 
    } 

    public String getField(int fieldNum) { 
        try { 
            int columnIndex = fieldNum; 
            return rs.getString(columnIndex); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            errorMessage = "Exception occured when returning field."; 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    public String getField(String fieldName) { 
        try { 
            String columnLabel = fieldName; 
            return rs.getString(columnLabel); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            errorMessage = "Exception occured when returning field."; 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    public void close() { 
        connection = null; 
    } 

    public String getErrorMessage() {  
        return errorMessage; 
    } 

    public boolean processUpdate(String statement) { 
        String sql = statement; 
        try { 
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
            int nbr = stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 
            return true; 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            errorMessage = "Database update failed."; 
            rs = null; 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try actually printing your stack traces and error messages.  That will probably tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your processUpdate method and your catch statement. Hope this helps you identify the problem.

```
} catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }
```